# pandoc: Error producing PDF

Tags: ubuntu, markdown, knitr, pandoc, miktex

**Goal**
Implementing a PDF function (a button on the webpage) that produces a PDF containing plots created by R that are shown on the webpage with markdown/knitr as shown in this tutorial: http://rprogramming.net/create-html-or-pdf-files-with-r-knitr-miktex-and-pandoc/

**Setup**

- Ubuntu server
- Installed MiKTeX for Ubuntu:

> sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys
>   D6BC243565B2087BC3F897C9277A7293F59E4889
>
> echo "deb http://miktex.org/download/ubuntu xenial universe" | sudo
>   tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/miktex.list
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install miktex

- Installed Pandoc

**R-code**

```
# Set working directory
setwd("/var/www/html/test_Knitr")

# Create .md, .html, and .pdf files
print("Debug1: packages loaded")

setwd("/var/www/html/DATA/test")
knit("/var/www/html/test_Knitr/reporting_style.Rmd")
print("Debug2: knit succesfull")

setwd("/var/www/html/DATA/test")
print("Debug3: setwd successfull")

markdownToHTML('/var/www/html/DATA/test/reporting_style.md', '/var/www/html/DATA/test/reporting_style.html', options=c("use_xhml"))
print("Debug4: markdownToHTML succesfull")

system("pandoc -s /var/www/html/DATA/test/reporting_style.html -o /var/www/html/DATA/test/reporting_style.pdf")
print("Debug5: pandoc succesfull")
```

**reporting_style.Rmd**

```
---
title: "Reporting template"
output: html_document
---


## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents.
```

**Problem**
The function runs perfectly until it reaches the last part `system("pandoc.."`
Here I receive an error message:

```
Sorry, but pdflatex did not succeed.

You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'MiKTeX::Core::MiKTeXException'
  what():  MiKTeX encountered an internal error.

pandoc: Error producing PDF
```

**Question**
I have been looking all over the internet, not able to find a solution for this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MiKTeX was originally a Windows-only distribution of TeX.  It has fairly recently been ported to Linux, and its web page says "Please beware that MiKTeX for Linux is still in an experimental stage".

You should probably use a more mainstream TeX.  I don't use Ubuntu so I'm not certain which distribution that is, but I'd guess it's TeX Live, http://tug.org/texlive/.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What would you recommend me to use to create a PDF out of a webpage that shows R plots on Ubuntu?

Comment: I don't use Ubuntu, but the general approach you're taking looks good:  R plus RMarkdown plus Pandoc plus TeX.

Comment: I have fixed the problem by removing miktex and installing texlive!